When is a vigilante response to injustice, morally justified?
We discussed a similar question, about facing tyranny and the threat of death, where I'd say the answer is clearer: Is the tyrannicide perpetrated by William Tell morally legitimate?
But what philosophers or philosophies have relevant thinking about vigilante justice, especially vengeance by murder for death of a loved one by corporate malice, that the state judicial system will not address?
Bonus points for any thinking that addresses wider social contexts and implications, like corrosive or beneficial impacts of acts or behaviours on society.

The problem is that people disagree and what is and isn't Injustice, and letting people act on those beliefs without sanity checking them with others has obvious dangers.

Surely the list of names would fill a book. Can you narrow down what kind of philosophers you're looking for? Under what ethical paradigms?

As Kant famously said: "Act only according to that maxim whereby people don't overwhelmingly rejoice on social media when you die"

IMHO, various liberation movements, especially those resorting to terror tactics, would make for a more lively debate than William Tell. Is using term terrorism vs. armed resistance make actions more/less morally legitimate?

@RogerV.: That belongs as a comment on the Tyrannicide thread. My question here regards personal vengeance..

Tyrannicude is very narrow. Obvious example is militant Palestinian group - it is not tyrants that they are targeting, and there's a great deal of personal vengeance in their actions. I feel  that situations like vengeance by murder for death of a loved one by corporate malice, that the state judicial system will not address, although not impossible today, belong more to tte romantic era than to modern times - modern reality is much uglier and less clear cut.

There is a convention or understanding within the philosophy of law that unjust or inapt laws can be defied and broken. I call it a convention or understanding because I can't really trace it to a specific author; it's just baked-in to the concept of Rights within Liberal theory. This isn't meant to encourage extralegal acts, but to apply trans-legal principles in opposition to written law, with the expectation that courts and juries will understand the problem and either excuse the ostensible crime or overturn the law itself. Civil disobedience has formed the core of many activist movements against established law; jury nullification is sometimes used to render a law moot; the modern Sovereign Citizen claims carte blanche exemption from law… This is a common enough move in legal and political spheres.
Vigilante behaviors could make a claim under this general rubric. However, vigilantism doesn't merely break a law that applies to the vigilante(s); it breaks laws that protect those the vigilantes confront. Generally speaking, with exceptions, modern legal systems explicitly deny citizens the right to enforce or adjudicate matters of law, granting that power solely to authorized and legitimized institutions. This is done specifically to avoid the problems associated with feuds, personal conflicts, and (yes) vigilantism. Justifying vigilantism legally is difficult enough, because vigilantes expressly take the law away from legitimate authority and enforce it themselves.  Justifying vigilantism morally is even more difficult, because vigilantism denies other people the rights of due process and fair trial.
The only time vigilantism might make sense morally is under conditions of such social and political breakdown that legitimate authority disappears or is rendered impotent. Then one might justify vigilantism, so long as the vigilantes are organized and disciplined enough to work as a substitute for legitimate authority.

Long article here: Lex iniusta non est lex: The implications of a misunderstanding.

Who decides if the vigilantes are "organized and disciplined enough"? The point of the "rule of law" is that the government is authorized to make these kinds of decisions. If there's political breakdown we essentially have anarchy, and vigilante justice simply remains as a last resort.

@Barmar: It's not a decision; it's a question of whether the vigilantes are trying to maintain something like rule-of-law, or whether they are selfishly exercising power in a power vacuum.

We justify vigilantism by saying the government will not do its job. The situation for a government that will not prosecute murder is very dangerous; the avenger of blood is of natural law that cannot be reasoned with but only suppressed by prosecuting murder openly.

@Joshua: I'm not sure who you're referencing by 'we', though I'll take it as a generic abstract. At any rate, the general answer to a government not doing its job is to politically convince the government to do its job. Generally speaking, if a government decides not to do something there's a reason for it, and what we want to do is investigate and address that reason. Trying to do the government's job by ourselves comes close to treason or insurrection.

@Joshua: Governments will prosecute (or otherwise deal with) those who try to usurp the government's powers. It doesn't matter how righteous the usurper feels, and it doesn't matter whether the usurper listens to reason. Murder is murder, regardless who gets killed, because the power to kill is something the government keeps to itself.

@TedWrigley: When the government permits known murderers to walk the streets, it should not be surprised when said murderers are killed on the streets. (It is important that I am not arguing these things should happen; I am arguing they will happen and can't be stopped.) I do not need to justify any particular incident to argue this position; and have done so elsewhere long before present events.

@Joshua: When a known murderer is killed on the street, that merely means that a new murderer is walking the streets. The government doesn't care what the reasons for murder are; it's just out to prevent murder. If someone wants to murder a murderer, they deserve to go to jail just as much as the first murderer did. Maybe they'll find life in prison worth it.

@Joshua: But I can see you're missing a key point.  The government can't stop a murder or any crime; the idea that law enforcement prevents crime is a silly myth. Law enforcement can only catch people during or after crimes, and take steps to redress the crimes after they are committed. Sometimes criminals walk free because the government can't build a case against them; that's due process in action. If someone violates due process by killing this known criminal, then that person is a criminal, and the government can try to build a case against them.

@Joshua: If we don't have due process, we don't have law. If we don't have law, we don't have rights. Like they say in the stories, if you set out on vengeance, dig two graves.

@TedWrigley: I do not dispute that; but when weighed in the balance it could be that a particular murder saves more lives than it takes. For example, it is plausible that striking down Putin would save Russian lives in the long run.

@Joshua: Sigh… I'm going to tell you a secret of moral reasoning: It's the means that justify the ends. It doesn't matter how bright and shiny the ends might appear from where you're standing. If the means you use to achieve them are dark and crapulent, your actions are not moral. Putin's actions may be horrific, but that's a stain on his character. Killing him would be a stain on the killer's. Maybe someone is willing to accept that stain, but they should see it as a stain, not a virtue. But we've gone far enough on this; let's drop it.

"There is a convention or understanding within the philosophy of law that unjust or inapt laws can be defied and broken" aka the collective realisation that (absolute) legalism is a bad moral framework (exemplified by the fact that it would literally exonerate Hitler)

The main ethical principle in vigilante justice, where a person or small group seeks violent 'vengeance' for some serious grievance, is the lex talionis -- the biblical "an eye for an eye, a tooth for a tooth". At least in the eyes of the vigilantes this morally justifies their actions or attempts to enact justice. As in Leviticus 24:17

17 Anyone who takes the life of a human being is to be put to death.
18 Anyone who takes the life of someone’s animal must make
restitution—life for life. 19 Anyone who injures their neighbor is to
be injured in the same manner: 20 fracture for fracture, eye for eye,
tooth for tooth. The one who has inflicted the injury must suffer the
same injury. 21 Whoever kills an animal must make restitution, but
whoever kills a human being is to be put to death. 22 You are to have
the same law for the foreigner and the native-born.

If there is to be punishment, then somehow it should be proportional to the punished crime. -- I believe this is generally accepted. (Exactly how to determine this proportionality -- and especially whether or not the death penalty or, for instance, maiming is ever justified -- is a different question!)
The remaining questions then are: (1) Should there be any retributive punishment for immoral acts? Is retribution ever justified? (2) Is violent, lethal retribution ever justified? (3) Should individual citizens be allowed or tolerated to enact violent retribution? (4) Who should administer justice -- is it justified to sometimes leave this to individuals acting outside of established institutions?
From an evolutionary, game-theoretical perspective enforcement of moral rules and punishment of violations needs to be "punished", otherwise those violations are in effect rewarded which undermines the stability of the system of current rules. (See for instance, Ken Binmore, Natural Justice.) Retributive justice is generally seen as rational and prudent, and we can show that it is necessary to stabilize the system. (Which doesn't imply anything about whether or not the system itself deservers to be stabilized, of course.)
In our current hierarchical societies with strong centralized nation states, the general sentiment seems to be that only the state has a legal (and moral?) monopoly to use violence and physical coercion (and only under certain legal restrictions -- even though those restrictions are frequently violated by those in power, including justices of the supreme court).
However, the legal system is always tainted by power and is not set up in some ideal utopian realm where all humans created the Law as ideally rational creatures under a veil of Rawlian ignorance ensuring fairness for all. So, any morally justified monopoly of the state is only valid insofar as the laws themselves are just and insofar as "we" can trust that those laws  can be applied (rather than systematically circumvented). Whether it is ultimately "justified" or not -- when social trust in the institutions breaks down, when the political and economic inequities in a society become as indecently large as in the US, when the basic institutions of law are no longer trusted to ensure redress, people will take the law in their own hands.

This appears to be a good place to point out the Biblical measure of retribution is misinterpreted in common understanding. A better interpretation is "only an eye for an eye, only a tooth for a tooth"; as it would have been understood in the time of the writing of the law. The contemporary laws of other nations tended to be harsher (at least, when dealing with those of the same social class).

I don't know the history, but I assume that the stipulation to apply the same laws to both tribesmen and strangers, was also an improvement compared to other contemporary moral systems. Even today, some politicians don't live up to this.

Morally justified according to whom?
Like this assumes that there is a only one definition of morality. But morality is just the distinction of things and actions into "good" and "evil" or even just into "good" and "bad".
But that tacitly implies that there is a goal or purpose. Because only if you have an ideal that you strive for, you'd be able to qualify and quantify the difference between an IS and an OUGHT state and make it a paradigm (moral) to change your actions accordingly.
However as the question of "What is the purpose, meaning or goal of life?" is famously unanswered or if you take the answer to be 42, it's quite unclear what the actual question was. It's quite bold to assume that morality is more than a person or group stating their preferences or what they'd like to avoid.
So the question is less of whether something is morally justified, but according to which person's moral it is justified or not or to which ends it's useful or useless.
Like idk the state might argue that theft is illegal, because it's unproductive labor or because it's disrupting carefully optimized processes by taking resources allocated for one thing and dispense it for another thing, because it increases the necessity for protection and security and adds to organizational overhead or because the lack of doing so undermines the state's role of protector of the people and keeper of the law, because crimes cause individual and social tension that threaten the stability of society and because society is a net benefit for it's members and so on or any other reason.
While on the other hand the thief might argue that the allocation of resources is actually very off, that people who have them don't need them and people who need them don't have them (and they're often not entirely wrong with that assessment), that a law which codifies such injustice is an unjust law and not even worth keeping in the first place and that the decline of a society that produces inequality and injustice and which rests upon exploitation and suppression is a good thing even if they don't consider their individual act to be revolutionary enough to actually facilitate that change, but rather as an immediate remedy to an illness.
People rarely hear or care for the perspective of the thief, because it's the state who makes, keeps and most importantly ENFORCES the law, but does it make that invalid? Is state authority on it's very core more than just might makes right or "power makes law/morality"?
And what does actually matter more? The perspective of the individual or the perspective of the groups and if it would be the latter who is allowed, able, willing to give that account?
Now there are certainly a lot of advantages in forming a group. You can reduce redundancy, enable division of labor and specialization, cover each other's weak spots, can utilize resources more efficiently, can make it through debilitating crisis without having to die because of it and so on. There's some reason why even the literal "lone wolf" more often than not actually has a pack and/or family.
However it also comes with downsides, namely that the freedom of the individual to do what they want to do is reduced. Suddenly there are other people that they need to take care of, who's wants, needs and abilities they have to account for and so on. So the world is no longer food or predator, but there are also "friends" who can be food or predator or neither and which require more complex interactions than poke it with a stick or smash it with a rock.
So groups have the possibility to be an advantage but they can also be a threat. The same solidarity that protects against the environment, can also be leveraged against it's members and be even more dangerous than the environment because the environment might not give a shit about you, whereas human predators know enough about the human condition to be a real problem.
And technically they can also be an in-between. Like the thief isn't particularly treated well by society both before and after the theft, but while society doesn't require the thief, the thief requires a society to be a thief, because without people producing stuff, he wouldn't be able to steal it, but would need to take the producing part themselves, which could be what they ultimately wanted and could be the reason of their perils and turning into a thief, but which could also be a situation of a predator without a prey.
So a lot of morality might not actually be driven by an abstract idea of "justice" or the following of an ideal of a "moral life", but are probably just motivated by keeping the group together and keeping their eyes on the objective.
Now individuals have a whole variety of goals and aspirations, especially when division of labor within a group leads to living in a different context with different problems, objectives and optimizations of their condition. So to keep people working as a team you somewhat need to bring and keep them on the same page with regards to what you need to do and why and how it's supposed to be done.
So that could be a democratic council or whatnot, though more often than not history has a bias of stories of leaders and chieftains, though whether that is justified or whether that is just the result of centralized power having the better options to craft one singular mass produced narrative over a multitude of different perspectives without the means to publish them...
So idk Hobbes apparently thought that these different interests would lead to a struggle all vs all which could only be overcome by crafting a universal morality, which he envisioned society to come together and hand that role to an absolute monarch, which even if they were a tyrant would still be preferable to whatever to the "state of nature".
Which you could say is just a continuation of prophets and high priests crafting a religion around their morality in order to pass of their vision as "the word of god", thus giving it "divine authority" and making it unquestionable.
Though in that regard Christianity, as a major source of morality in the eurocentric world, is both an archetype and an outlier. It copies both the all powerful, allmighty god from Judaism, but contrasts it with the human form of Jesus Christ (where again Christ is not just a surname but a title of power).
In a sense it subverts the expectation of society. The highest god lives like the lowest beggar and surrounds himself with criminals, prostitutes and those society deems categorically "immoral". Also the "love thy neighbor as thyself" transforms solidarity from a means to an end to an end in itself. And rather than instructing people to live by and for the law, he argues that the law is meant to help the people and occasionally breaks and bends it where it doesn't fit. Also arguing that the positions of power, wealth and privilege are temporary compared to the permanent afterlife and that they are rather a burden than a privilege is a radical subversion of what is considered "moral" (good) and evil within society.
At the same time he also doesn't actually rebel against the status quo, against the law, the emperor, the priests (sure occasional disputes, but no revolution), instead he argues people should give the emperor what is his and give god what is his and that the latter is more important. So he doesn't so much challenge them for value, but challenges what it is that they think is value.
Yet it's ultimate rise to power came with the becoming the state religion of the Roman Empire and being exported via colonialism and as such it became the archetype of the oppressive and exploitative religion, abusing divine authority to justify very earthly authority.
Yet which also creates some idea of moral patchwork which is contradictory. Which has elements of submission to authority. Of challenging authority (even if just in favor of a higher authority). Of individual duties and a personal progression. Of societal norms and status disputes. Of focusing on objective. Of universality and of subjectivity and so on.
Also an obvious problem is that while divine law and the practice of unquestionable laws make for a compelling narrative, they don't actually work. Like in many of those cases the full weight of the crime is placed on the criminal (and that is often still the case today), but often enough they overlook that the criminal might not act out of their own volition, but out of an urgent necessity and of an inability to live under the conditions of society and mandated by the law.
So with the enlightenment you had a shift from the perspective of the law maker as the protector of society and the keeper of law and of the dissident as the immoral criminal. Towards one where the criminal is in fact the hero trying to break free from the chains of a tyrannic oppressor.
Again likely the social status and the biases of those being able to and willing to write such accounts might have added considerably to that.
Though under that moral paradigm of course the vigilante is morally justified to take matters into their own hand if it's society, the law, the tyrannical force that oppresses them. In that narrative that is merely an act of self-defense and when that leads to the dissolution of society and the destruction of moral? GOOD! There's no virtue in what didn't work in the first place.
Which is a powerful and compelling narrative, which took the world by storm and to this day even the most vile and despicable criminals often employ that kind of narrative to justify their crimes.
Because there's a crucial difference between the fight against a tyrant and the fight against tyranny.
You can very much fight a tyrant and not have problem with tyranny just with that particular tyrant, so if idk you take the position instead, things might look differently.
So many "liberators" ended up being the thing they set out to fight, though of course they rarely characterize that as failure of the revolution...
However does that mean that within the framework of the individual's perspective, the vigilante responses are unjust? Not necessarily. The individual does what they think is good and fights what they think is evil, so they're doing what is moral within their perspective (unless they realize the problem with their own action).
The problem is rather the other way around in that if you end up in a position where you what you do is perceived as injustices by others, and if you rule by force that is very likely to happen, that would attribute the same morality towards vigilante justice AGAINST YOU.
So the problem is not that your action is morally unjust (in that framework), but that vigilante responses in general aren't unjust, which in the worst case would just be a violent free for all.
So in a sense the state is not the end of violence and the reign of justice, it's merely the monopoly of violence or in other words: ORGANIZED violence. So while the individual has problems to assess the full picture, to remove themselves and their emotions from the situation and to act proportional and in ways that resolve the conflict rather than intensifying it. That state can have some of these options. The police can research a case often better than the individual can, a judge is not emotionally involved in the case and the entire process takes speed and tension out of the situation.
So as a result the emotionalized disorganized chaotic force of vengeance is replaced with a more boring, formal, regulated, sterile form of jurisdiction. Which in many cases has a positive effect if two hotheads get at each other's throat than just giving it a second to cool down, telling the respective account to other people and have have a mediator can already work wonders.
While in other cases you can achieve the exact opposite, where people perceive themselves at the receiving end of not just individual, but institutionalized injustice and where as such even more forceful and sweeping violence is appropriate given the disproportional power wielded by the competing factions...
Now you could probably also point to Kant and the categorical imperative or to Nietzsche and his subversion of Christian morality or what he confuses for that, but ultimately we've still not figured out a working morality or how it should balance the collective and the individual. So TL;DR you can't answer that in the absolute but would need a framework. E.g. the state would consider it immoral because it violates the monopoly of violence and jeopardizes the cohesion of society and it's legitimization narrative. The vigilante probably considers it justified, because it is an injustice that severely reduces the utility of society for them and as such probably sees it's as either self-defense or a direct or indirect aversion of harm from themselves or others.
Now practically it's also problematic to argue that in the abstract because it crucially matters whether the vigilante is even correct in their assessment of the situation in the first place. However that assessment is subjective, while your assessment of their assessment is also subjective no matter how much people give it the veneer of objectivity, so yeah...
So again it somewhat comes down to the perspective that you take in that.


Your question stated in the second section presupposes that a state
judicial system exist. In particular accusations can be brought at
court.
I assume that the state also owns the monopoly of violence to
execute in case of judgement.

IMO the only legal way is to apply to a higher court, e.g., the
International Criminal Court in The Hague, Netherland.

I don’t know any argument from ethics which supports vigilante
justice in the presence of a state judical system.
On the contrary,
I consider it an important political improvement when vigilante
justice has been substituted by a state judicial system grounded on the declaration of human rights.



What about the circumstance of corruption? Hobbes said revolution's never justified, nearly everyone since accepts there are circumstances where it is. Isn't your stance akin to Hobbes? Or perhaps Kant, who thought it was immoral to lie even to save a life. There are circumstances when I think almost anyone, in practice, would say it's justified to take the law into our own hands, as a practical matter. Surely there are philosophers who have thought about this? Maybe as example consider the assassination of R.E.H. Dyer after he faced no consequences for ordering the Jallianwala Bagh massacre.

Locke and Rousseau held that citizens have the right to rebel. Almost any current state has in fact been brought about by violent action (where the citizens where either victors or vanquished) whether this was justified or not. Ancient Confucian philosophy (e.g. Mengzi) also accepted the right to rebel. If a ruler lost the implicit consent and compliance of the people, this basically meant the ruler lost the "mandate of heaven" (more or less corresponding to the natural right to rule).

"On the contrary, I consider it an important political improvement when vigilante justice has been substituted by a state judicial system."
Without any caveats or conditions? Because that's just legalism, and that is a highly questionable moral stance

@Hobbamok You are right. I made an addition in my last sentence.

@JoWehler I fully agree with the new version. Partly because it directly allows for vigilante justice in the USA (who consistently refuses to sign human rights treaties and add significant reservations when it does)

@Hobbamok The USA have signed the UNO declaration of humans rights, of course. The problem: They do not sign membership of the International Criminal Court and not of the International Court of Justice.

@JoWehler and they declared the treaties non-executing. Which means they're very explicit about not wanting any accountability whatsoever. At which point I consider them basically non-signatories

In Utilitarianism: it depends (in the case of current news vigilantiism, probably yes).
[This entire answer is exclusively in the context of utilitarianism]
One one hand state structures are - if they are even trying or capable - slow at enforcing justice. So vigilante justice is a good remedy to this, as executing more justice generally improves societal happiness / wellbeing.
However, vigilantism comes with a few downsides that - depending on the case - may outweigh the benefit of swift justice.
For one, state judicial systems are so slow because they - ideally - respect rights, due process and other limitations imposed to protect innocents from falsely being prosecuted. While this also sometimes protects (morally) guilty people, the chance of targeting someone innocent with vigilante action has to be factored into the considerations of whether the action(s) will better society overall.
Secondly, even with an absolutely guilty target, the reduction of trust in the state monopoly on violence (whose value under utilitarianism heavily depends on the context) and the consequential destabilization of society (to whatever degree) can also be a major factor that may outweigh the good of any vigilante action.
Both of these are very hard to predict or ensure accurately by a layman, which is why vigilantism is only a good choice under exceptional circumstances.
However, both of them hinge on the state, it's laws and the judicial system are working towards the benefit of society, which isn't always a given either.


is a vigilante response to injustice morally justified?

Yes.
But only if the vigilante justice is guaranteed to find the right bad guy and mete an appropriate punishment. Since that's rarely true of an angry crowd, we have formal systems to evaluate guilt and apply punishment.
